# Where to compile a C++ program?

Tags: c++

I am new to coding in **C++** and I am not sure where I can compile a C++ program, I am learning C++ through a website that already has a place to compile the code built into it. I know how to compile a program by using these commands: `g++ [program name].cpp -o [name you want to give]` and then do `./[name you gave]`. **I want to know where I can compile my code outside of this website.**
Thanks.

Comment: On your computer. I don't really understand the question.

Comment: depending on your OS, you will need to download and install a compiler / IDE.

Comment: You are permitted to choose the folders on your computer. If you have a windows PC you probably want to install Visual Studio 2019 Community and create c++ console projects inside the IDE.

Comment: The answers in the duplicate apply for installing the latest versions of GCC as well of course.

Comment: Personally, I recommend loading up a laptop with an open source (free) IDE and compiler, then going to a beach and compiling at the beach.  Although you may have be cautious about the sand getting into the laptop.  Perhaps the Redwood Forest in Northern California, U.S.A.

Comment: When installing a GCC-or-similar compiler on Windows, I use a set-up too similar [to what's described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) for it to be worth my time writing another answer. When not on Windows, there's usually a GCC-or-similar compiler already installed.

Comment: When visiting California, make sure to do it when A) it's not during a global pandemic and B) California's not on fire. That's made things tricky of late.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of places you can write code for c++. Usually people will use IDEs such as

Visual Studio Code

Code::Blocks

CLion

Eclipse

CodeLite
etc...

Comment: But OP asked precisely about command line and `g++`, not for an arbitrary IDE.

Comment: He said " I know how to compile a program by using these commands: g++...", He asked "I want to know where I can compile my code outside of this website."